# Adding facebook like button creates new page. Possible to merge/fix?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I created a facebook page for my company and invited my friends to like it.  Win.

Now I want to add a like button on my company's outside website....

- I "logged in as page" for my company.
- I then clicked on the marketing tab > add a like button.
- created the code using Iframe.

However, when I paste the code on my website, the likes (and all my hard work) starts over.  It also creates a brand new page on facebook... argh.

Obviously, I can recreate my page on the newly created FB page and re-invite all my friends, but this wastes weeks of work and annoys my already pseudo friends.  Any ideas before I do this?

For reference, here is the like iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

open graph...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/image.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxx" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `href` attribute to the page you've already created.
You cannot use the og-tags on your own homepage then but the Facebook-Page attributes are used.

so change

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2F*your facebook page (with escaped slashes and so on)*&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: This associates likes to my facebook page, but for SEO reasons I would prefer to have the likes associated with my outside website. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't think it is. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for on the same issue. But what is 'with escaped slashes and so on'? Could you show that to me?

Comment: @Clint, you have to escape the slashes so it will not interfere with the real URI. E.g. `/ => %2F` or `: => %3A` etc.